# Framer motion animating react components transition problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I'm conditionally rendering 2 header components. I want using framer motion when switching between the 2 to add some animation that's it. the only problem is when I transition, instead of the first component ease out and second one ease in for smoother transition, the first component sits for a brief second before leaving which makes the container height double since there's 2 containers.

Here's the first component

```
export default function HeaderTextLandlord () {

    return (
        <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
            <h1 className="mt-10 max-w-2xl text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:text-6xl sm:leading-tight flex flex-wrap items-center">
                <span>No more applicant</span>
                <span className="relative ml-2">
                    <span className={'bg-primary-100'}>overload</span>. We curate top tenants for you
                    <ArrowDownSvgIcon className="absolute -top-28 -right-8"/>
                     <SmileSvgIcon className="absolute -bottom-14 right-10"/>
                </span>
            </h1>tton>
                <NotificationSvg className="absolute -top-8 right-0"/>
            </div>
        </motion.div>
    );
}
```

And here's the second component:

```
export default function HeaderTextTenant () {
    return (
        <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }}  animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        >
            <h1 className="mt-10  max-w-lg text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:text-6xl sm:leading-tight">
                No more
                <span className={'bg-primary-100 px-3 relative ml-2'}>search
                            <ArrowSvgIcon className="absolute -top-16 -right-20"/>
                        </span>
                <span className={'relative'}>stress. Homes seek you <SmileSvgIcon className="absolute bottom-3 -right-48"/></span>
            </h1>ficationSvg className="absolute -top-8 right-0"/>
        </motion.div>
    );
}
```

Here's my header

```
export default function Header () {
    const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState('tenant');
    const onTabChange = val => {
        setCurrentTab(val);
    };
     
    return (
                <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                        <AnimatePresence wait>
                            {currentTab === 'tenant' && (
                                    <HeaderTextTenant />
                            )}
                            {currentTab === 'landlord' && (
                                    <HeaderTextLandlord />
                            )}
                        </AnimatePresence>
                 </div>
)
```

Please note that I'm using next.js 13.4